# Google Kubernetes Engine(GKE)にデプロイできない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kubernetes

[GKEにRailsをdeployしてみる](https://www.enisias.cloud/kubernetes/483/)
を参考に今rubyonrails行っているのですが

myrails_deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myrails
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myrails
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myrails
        image: makotooishi/myrails:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        env:
          - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
            valueFrom: 
                #secretを参照
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: myrails-secret
                  key: db_password
          - name: DB_HOST_NAME
            value: bold-monkey-mariadb
        command: ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "server", "-p", "3000", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

のところでエラーがでます。

```
error: error parsing myrails_deployment.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 23: did not find expected key
```

`create secret generic myrails-secret --from-literal=db_password=password`
で再度作り直し

`kubectl get secrets myrails-secret -o yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  db_password: cGFzc3dvcmQ=
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2019-01-31T09:15:28Z"
  name: myrails-secret
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "1199"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/myrails-secret
  uid: c03d81cf-2538-11e9-b191-42010a920003
type: Opaque
```

のように作成できました。
その後myrails_deployment.yaml:
を行ったんですが次に下記のエラーがでましたので、

```
error: error validating "myrails_deployment.yaml": error validating data: [ValidationError(Deployment.spec): unknown field "command" in io.k8s.api.extensions.v1beta1.DeploymentSpec, ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[0]): unknown field "key" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.EnvVar]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

myrails_deployment.yaml:
を下記のように書き換えました

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myrails
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myrails
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myrails
        image: makotooishi/myrails:latest
        ports:
      - containerPort: 3000
   command: ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "s", "-p", "3000", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
        env:
          - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
            name: myrails-secret
            key: db_password
```

で次に下記エラーがでました

```
error: error parsing myrails_deployment.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 16: did not find expected key
```

何とか動かしたいのですが、誰か教えてください。お願いします

Answer (score 0, accepted):

23行目で指定しているkey

> ```
> key: db_password
> ```

が無い、というエラーなので、本来あるべき通りにSecretリソースが作成されていない、つまり、参照されているページで言うところの

> ```
> kubectl create secret generic myrails-secret --from-literal=db_password=password
> ```

コマンドが正しく実行されていない(例えば `db_password` という文字列を打ち間違えているとか)が原因ではないでしょうか。

`kubectl get secrets myrails-secret -o yaml`コマンドで設定したkeyを確認できます

```
$ kubectl get secrets myrails-secret -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
db_password: cGFzc3dvcmQ=
kind: Secret
(後略)
```

ので、想定と異なっているのであれば一旦該当Secretを削除して

```
kubectl delete secrets myrails-secret
```

再度、件の`kubectl create`コマンドを実行すれば良いかと思います。